# Advanced Switch statement

Tags: javascript, algorithm, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I want to loop through an array of projects, filter out elements with multiple conditions, and push them to the destinated array.
The result should have 4 arrays containing all the projects that met each specific array's condition. Something like this

```js
// 4 cases of the parent array
const arrayOverDeadline_overBudget = []
const arrayOverDeadline_withinBudget = []

const arrayOneMonthDeadline_OverBudget = []
const arrayOneMonthDeadline_withinBudget = []

export const filterArray = (array) => {
  const today = moment();
  const oneMonthBefore = moment().add(1, "m");

  array.forEach((item) => {
    switch (item.deadline && item.budget) {
      // over deadline && over budget
      // (deadline <= today) && (budget > 100%)
      case params.deadline <= today && params.budget >= 100:
        break;

      // over deadline && within budget 
      // (deadline <= today) && (80% < budget < 100%)
      case params.deadline < today &&
        params.budget < 100 &&
        params.budget > 80:
        break;

      // within deadline && within budget 
      // (today < deadline < oneMonthBefore) && (80% <= budget < 100%)
      case params.deadline > today &&
      params.deadline < oneMonthBefore &&
      params.budget < 100 &&
      params.budget >= 80:        
      break;

      // within deadline && over budget
      // (today < deadline < oneMonthBefore) && (budget >= 100%)
      case params.deadline > today &&
      params.deadline < oneMonthBefore &&
      params.budget > 100:
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  });
};
```

I looked for some answers and found [Flags and Bitmasks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/operators#Example:_Flags_and_bitmasks) but wasn't sure how to implement it in my cases.
I also worry about the time complexity of my method.
Any tips or ideas would be very welcome and appreciated.

Update:

1. Added conditions.
2. The purpose of the question was to ask whether there are more efficient ways to distribute the elements in the array to the desired location. I have tried the `if..elseif...else` approach but I just wanted to know if there are "cleaner" ways, and it doesn't have to use `switch` statement.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect your code (as presented) to accomplish? It does not make any sense to me whatsoever.

Comment: `case` shouldn't have a condition. It has a value that's just compared with the `switch()` argument for equality.

Comment: You should just be doing `if ... else if ...`

Comment: @Barmar multiple `if-else` clauses will work, but a better, cleaner way does exist imo. Voting to reopen

Comment: @AbhinavMathur If you have a solution better than all the ones in the duplicate, I've reopened so you can post it.

Comment: @PM77-1 I want to allocate every item that met the condition in the cases and push them to the correct array defined above arrayOverDeadline_withinBudget, etc.

Comment: Have you actually tried to run your code?

Comment: @Barmar added the answer, you can decide if you want to close the question or not

Comment: I run the code. But I wanted to make it cleaner.

Comment: Is there any case for `budget <= 80`?

Comment: You have `budget > 100` and `budget < 100`. What about `budget == 100`?

Comment: Hi, I have added the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply break this down to 2 boolean variables:

1. `bool1 = is project over the deadline`
2. `bool2 = is project over the budget`

Create an int from these variables (`bool1` right shifted once + `bool2`) to get a value between `[0,3]`, and then you can map this value to the target array.

Example:

1. `bool1 = 0, bool2 = 0`. Target value = `00 (binary) = 0`. Target value `0` maps to `under deadline, under budget`.
2. `bool1 = 0, bool2 = 1`. Target value = `01 (binary) = 1`. Target value `1` maps to `under deadline, over budget`.
3. `bool1 = 1, bool2 = 0`. Target value = `10 (binary) = 2`. Target value `2` maps to `over deadline, under budget`.
4. `bool1 = 1, bool2 = 1`. Target value = `11 (binary) = 3`. Target value `3` maps to `over deadline, over budget`.

You can generate this target value using just one line of code, and then using these cases to decide the destination array should remove the need for writing complicated if-else blocks.

###### Edit:

Adding a sample implementation:

```js
const budget = 100,
  deadline = 100
const item_budget = 120,
  item_deadline = 80
const b1 = Number(item_deadline > deadline)
const b2 = Number(item_budget > budget)
const target = (b1 << 1) + b2
switch (target) {
  case 0:
    console.log("under deadline, under budget")
    break;
  case 1:
    console.log("under deadline, over budget")
    break;
  case 2:
    console.log("over deadline, under budget")
    break;
  default:
    console.log("over deadline, over budget")
}
// prints "under deadline, over budget"
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show the actual code, not just describe it.

Comment: @Barmar added an example

Comment: Hi, much sorry for the late reply. Been busy all day. 
Could you kindly explain this `const target = (b1 << 1) + b2` please? Why do we need to shift right once and + bool2?

Comment: @Henry. that is the equivalent of creating a 2-bit binary number with the left bit as `b1` and right bit as `b2`